# Different results in phpmyadmin and php - related to datetime?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, phpmyadmin

I have a single SQL query where the results differ when being run through phpmyadmin and through my script. My query uses relative times, but I thought UTC times were universal? And even if they're server based, they're both being run on the same server.

This is the sql:

```
SELECT id, question_text, 
(CASE WHEN (start_time = 0 OR start_time > UTC_TIMESTAMP) THEN 'unasked' 
WHEN start_time < UTC_TIMESTAMP AND (end_time = 0 OR end_time > UTC_TIMESTAMP) THEN 'in-progress' 
WHEN start_time < UTC_TIMESTAMP AND end_time < UTC_TIMESTAMP THEN 'completed' 
ELSE 'unknown' END) AS status 
FROM `questions` WHERE survey_id = 1
```

The result from phpmyadmin is:

1
What is your favorite color?
completed

2
What is the cutest animal in the world?
completed

But the result from my script is:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [question_text] => What is your favorite color? [status] => completed ) Array ( [id] => 2 [question_text] => What is the cutest animal in the world? [status] => unknown )
```

The second element/element in question has start-date:2016-04-30 15:20:00 and end-date:
2016-10-13 20:40:35.

Comment: I suspect you have [`SessionTimeZone`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_SessionTimeZone) configuration set in your `config.inc.php`, so PhpMyAdmin is using that timezone instead of the server timezone.

Comment: What's the datatype of `start_time` and `end_time`? If you compare with `UTC_TIMESTAMP` it should be `INT`, not `DATETIME`.

Comment: Ah, maybe that's it. It is a datetime. What time function should I be using to create and compare datetimes?

Comment: `NOW()` is the current time as a datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the table columns are `DATETIME`, you should compare with `NOW()`, which is the current time as a datetime in the server's timezone.

```
SELECT id, question_text, 
       (CASE WHEN (start_time = 0 OR start_time > NOW()) THEN 'unasked' 
             WHEN (end_time = 0 OR end_time > NOW()) THEN 'in-progress' 
             ELSE 'completed') AS status 
FROM `questions` WHERE survey_id = 1
```

I'v also simplified the `WHEN` expressions. Since they're tried in order, you don't need to check `start_time < NOW()` in the 2nd `WHEN`, since the first one would already handle that case. And since you only tested `>` and `>`, it would have failed and reported "unknown" if one of the times was exactly now (the opposite of `>` is `<=`, not `<`). And with all these simplifications, it's not possible for there to be an unknown case.